# Why does Hibernate not return connections to pool on Wildfly 12?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, connection, wildfly

I've got a running app on Weblogic 12 using Hibernate. Now I need to make it compatible with Wildfly 12. We're using Hibernate as ORM here, config follows.

Problem now is, that Wildfly's connection pool runs out of conns after a few requests, since obviously Hibernate does not return elements back to it.

connection.release_mode is set correctly (I think) in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <property name="transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>
    <property name="transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
    <property name="connection.release_mode">after_statement</property>
```

We're using container managed transactions in our EJBs, DB is Oracle.

Datasource is configured like this:

```
           <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/psqlWSDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521/XXX</connection-url>
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <initial-pool-size>1</initial-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>XXX</user-name>
                    <password>XXX</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:158)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:255)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:332)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:238)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)  
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)  
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)  
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)  
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)  
at com.jquick.webservices.components.lock.ejb.LockManagerBusiness$$$view33.hasLock(Unknown Source)  
at com.jquick.webservices.session.DefaultService.hasLock(DefaultService.java:630)  
at com.jquick.webservices.components.um.service.UMService.getBenutzer(UMService.java:1532)  
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
at com.jquick.webservices.session.invoker.InvokerBean.doInvokeService(InvokerBean.java:245)  
... 248 more  
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection  
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)  
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)  
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)  
at com.jquick.webservices.components.lock.dao.LockDAOHibernate.findByApplicationIdAndItemId(LockDAOHibernate.java:91)  
at com.jquick.webservices.components.lock.ejb.LockManagerEJB.hasLockFromMe(LockManagerEJB.java:247)  
at com.jquick.webservices.components.lock.ejb.LockManagerEJB.hasLock(LockManagerEJB.java:230)  
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor175.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)  
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)  
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)  
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)  
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)  
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:253)  
... 288 more  
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection  
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)  
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)  
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)  
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:118)  
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:145)  
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)  
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)  
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)  
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1995)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1925)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2702)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2685)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2517)  
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2512)  
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)  
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:384)  
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)  
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490)  
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)  
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)  
... 315 more  
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/psqlWSDS  
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)  
at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)  
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)  
at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)  
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:115)  
... 335 more  
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/psqlWSDS  
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)  
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:430)  
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)  
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)  
... 339 more  
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])  
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:570)  
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:714)  
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:613)  
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)  
... 342 more
```

I tried changing the release_mode to other settings with no effect, Hibernate does not release connections to the pool.

Flushing the connections from Wildfly's datasource statistics page releseases the connections.

So any hints, how to get the connection pool running as intended would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Best regards

Mark.

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact issue. Have you found a resolution yet?

Comment: nothing so far - focus has moved away from Wildfly for the time being, for the little of testing we are doing now we are using WFs CCM, which not a prod strategy but for now we'll stick to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that injecting the `EntityManager` the way I would in OpenJPA was causing Hibernate to create multiple `SessionFactory` objects and thereby caused the connection leak. See documentation (Section 1.1) http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

I changed my app to use a singleton class to create one `SessionFactory` object and then on each query get that factory object to create the `Session` object.

```
//Session manager singleton
@Singleton
public class DbSessionManager {
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public EntityManager createSession() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    } }


//Data access class
public class DbWriter{

    @EJB
    private DbSessionManager db;

    @Override
    public EntityDao save(EntityDao newEnt)  {
        EntityManager em = db.createSession();

        try {
            em.merge(newEnt);
        } catch (NoResultException x) {
            em.persist(newEnt);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

        return newEnt;
    } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - we are using the Hibernate Session API, not the EntityManager.